# IOS parse JSON data in another thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, location

I am currently working on an application which is parsing some JSON data in the APPdelegate class when the location is changed.

My question is: " How is the most appropriate way doing it ?" Currently when it is parsing the data the application is "frozen" until the data has been loaded.

I need some advice :)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways of course, including `NSThread`, `NSOperation` and old-fashioned `libpthread`. But what I find the most convenient (especially for simple background tasks) is `libdispatch` also called [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

Using dispatch queues you can quickly delegate a time-consuming task to a separate thread (or more precisely, execution queue - GCD decides whether it's a thread or an asynchronous task). Here's the simplest example:

```
// create a dispatch queue, first argument is a C string (note no "@"), second is always NULL
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);

// execute a task on that queue asynchronously
dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{
    [self doSomeJSONReadingAndParsing];

    // once this is done, if you need to you can call
    // some code on a main thread (delegates, notifications, UI updates...)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.viewController updateWithNewData];
    });
});

// release the dispatch queue
dispatch_release(jsonParsingQueue);
```

The above code will read JSON data in a separate execution queue, not blocking the UI thread. This is just a simple example and there's a lot more to GCD, so take a look at the documentation for more info.

Comment: Nice way doing it :) i will look more into it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSOperation` to handle it.

You may follow this tutorial: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

And apple document: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `NSURConnections` and fetch data asynchronously (or a third party library like [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)) to bring your data. If you do everything in your main thread your User Interface will freeze till it handles dowloading&parsing ect. So, take a look at [iOS Multithreading](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html). And a last point, [Locations Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Locations/Introduction/Intro.html)  of Apple gives exactly what you want:)